# Is there a way to log stacktrace which called System.exit in Java

Tags: java, stack-trace, systemexit

I think there is a way to do this with `SecurityManager`, but I don't want to introduce it in an App just for this.

Is there a way to catch and log stacktrace of what called exit() using some other solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using shutdown hook?
It could be like this:

```
Thread printStackTracesOnShutdownHook = new Thread(() -> {
    LOG.info("Shutdown hook called");
    for (Map.Entry<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> pair : 
             Thread.getAllStackTraces().entrySet()) {
        LOG.info(pair.getKey() + " : " + Arrays.toString(pair.getValue()));
    }
});

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(printStackTracesOnShutdownHook);
```

You can add this code somewhere in your application (where it will be executed). Then on shutdown `printStackTracesOnShutdownHook` will write to logs all stackTraces. And you will be able to find from these stackTraces where `System.exit()` was called.